# Samsung UE50TU8500 - Youtube progress bar dark background, before was transparent

Tags: youtube

On the above Samsung Smart TV, on the Youtube app, when a video is playing and I press arrow up (to see the progress bar) or Pause (same result), the progress bar area, including icons "Channel", "CC" and "More" now have a dark, almost black background.
This must have happened last night (4 Nov 2021). I noticed it this morning.
Before the background was transparent.
Also, the name of the video and the name of the channel, in top-left of the video, now also have a black background.

What I've tried:

-- Reboot the TV by holding the power button until it restarts

-- Reinstall the Youtube app

Another small thing: every time I click to play a video, the word 'Loading' appears, whereas before the videos played straight away. The Pause icon on the screen is now much bigger and with black background.

Does anyone know what happened? A dodgy midnight update perhaps, that didn't go through QA? Just...

Screenshot:

[image: Youtube black background Samsung TV]

Comment: I'm having the same thing with my Hisense Smart TV.

Comment: Suddenly the problem fixed itself. Bizarre. At some point I got a message saying 'Could not connect', do this and that with the remote. I didn't do anything, and then when it connected and Youtube fired up, all was back as before.